# How can I append an xml with namespaces to another xml in php, DOMDocument?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm trying to generate some XML with XML parts in PHP, with DOMDocument, and I need to append two XML parts.

I have two name-spaced XML parts. One for an "envelope" with datas, and one for looped datas, and I need to put these together. Put the looped datas to the envelope.

I've already tried a lot of examples from StackOverflow, but they do not mention how to do with namespaces.

Comment: So, to summarize, you need the second fragment appended, _verbatim_, as child of the first fragment's top element? Because that barely even requires a DOM parser, that's basically a file operation at best. Of course, if this is just "example" code, please make sure to create a [mcve] with "real enough" data, to show what goes wrong. You claim you have namespace declarations, but your example XML doesn't show any, so we have no way of knowing what your data actually looks like and what you're really doing.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans , I've updated the examples, removed the dummy code and replaced with actual code

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd fragments are not well-formed (so technically are not XML) as namespace prefixes are used but never declared within respective document.

Comment: Do you have that actual comment in the XML file? Or do you just have one XML file, to XML fragment files, and you to effect `appended = secondfile.rootNode.append(thirdfile)` followed by a `firstfile.find('urn:ScheduleMessage').append(appended)`? (ignoring the fact that those functions don't exist, I'm mostly asking to see if I understand what you're actually trying to do)

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, you need to properly generate the XML fragments and avoid the error:

> namespace error : Namespace prefix urn on Period is not defined

To incorporate namespace prefixes use [`createElementNS()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelementns.php) instead of `createElement()`:

```
$urn_uri = "urn:entsoe.eu:edi:ess:schedulemessage:3:3";

$period = $dom->createElementNS(urn_uri, "urn:Period");
$timeInterval = $dom->createElementNS(urn_uri, "urn:TimeInterval");
$resolution = $dom->createElementNS(urn_uri, "urn:Resolution");

...
```

Once each fragment is properly generated, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files, since it maintains the `document()` function to parse from external XML files. PHP can run XSLT 1.0 scripts using its [php/xsl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) library (might require enabling the extension).

Below assumes namespaces are properly defined in root of 2nd and 3rd fragments. **NOTE**: this XSLT solution will not work if fragments are not well-formed.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:aut="http://www.domain.xy/OSB/Authentication/" 
                              xmlns:sch="http://www.domain.xy/schedule/ScheduleManager/" 
                              xmlns:urn="urn:entsoe.eu:edi:ess:schedulemessage:3:3">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="urn:ScheduleMessage">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document('2nd Part.xml')/urn:ScheduleTimeSeries"/>     
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="urn:ScheduleTimeSeries">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('3rd Part.xml')/*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP** *(run transformation only on first part)*

```
// LOAD XML AND XSLT
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->load('1st Part.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');   
$xsl->load('Script.xsl');

// INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

// RUN TRANSFORMATION
$newXML = $proc->transformToDoc($xml);

// ECHO TO CONSOLE
echo $newXML;

// SAVE TO FILE
file_put_contents('Output.xml', $newXML);
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:aut="http://www.domain.xy/OSB/Authentication/" xmlns:sch="http://www.domain.xy/schedule/ScheduleManager/" xmlns:urn="urn:entsoe.eu:edi:ess:schedulemessage:3:3">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <aut:mekAuth>
      <username>username</username>
      <password>p455w0rd</password>
    </aut:mekAuth>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <sch:receiveScheduleRequest>
      <urn:ScheduleMessage>
        <urn:MessageIdentification v="xyz" />
        <urn:MessageVersion v="34" />
        <urn:MessageType v="xyz" />
        <urn:ProcessType v="xyz" />
        <urn:ScheduleClassificationType v="xyz" />
        <urn:SenderIdentification v="xyz" codingScheme="xyz" />
        <urn:SenderRole v="xyz" />
        <urn:ReceiverIdentification v="xyz" codingScheme="xyz" />
        <urn:ReceiverRole v="xyz" />
        <urn:MessageDateTime v="2019-06-23T23:23:28Z" />
        <urn:ScheduleTimeInterval v="2019-06-22T22:00Z/2019-06-23T22:00Z" />
        <urn:ScheduleTimeSeries>
          <urn:SendersTimeSeriesIdentification v="xyz" />
          <urn:SendersTimeSeriesVersion v="34" />
          <urn:BusinessType v="xyz" />
          <urn:Product v="xyz" />
          <urn:ObjectAggregation v="xyz" />
          <urn:InArea v="xyz" codingScheme="xyz" />
          <urn:MeteringPointIdentification v="xyz" codingScheme="xyz" />
          <urn:InParty v="xyz" codingScheme="xyz" />
          <urn:MeasurementUnit v="KWT" />
          <urn:Period>
            <urn:TimeInterval v="2019-06-22T22:00Z/2019-06-23T22:00Z" />
            <urn:Resolution v="PT15M" />
            <urn:Interval>
              <urn:Pos v="1" />
              <urn:Qty v="0" />
            </urn:Interval>
            <urn:Interval>
              <urn:Pos v="2" />
              <urn:Qty v="0" />
            </urn:Interval>
            <urn:Interval>
              <urn:Pos v="3" />
              <urn:Qty v="0" />
            </urn:Interval>
            <urn:Interval>
              <urn:Pos v="4" />
              <urn:Qty v="0" />
            </urn:Interval>
          </urn:Period>
        </urn:ScheduleTimeSeries>
      </urn:ScheduleMessage>
    </sch:receiveScheduleRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```